# Swift Hide StackView into a TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

In my table view, I have 4 horizontal stackViews with data. I would like to hide some one them according to data.

I have well created the connexion in my TableViewCell file by doing :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var stackViewComment: UIStackView!
```

and I can well access to it into my viewController.

However, when I try to assign a property :

```
 cell.stackViewComment?.isHidden = true
```

I have the error message "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

How can access to my stackView property ?

Many thanks

Comment: When do you call this: "cell.stackViewComment?.isHidden = true" ?

Comment: I call this function into my viewController inside the function  :                                             `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide initially you have to do that in Interface Builder, if later, then you can do that not earlier than in viewDidLoad

Comment: I want to hide it by cell depending the content of my array as Prototype cells. I would avoid to use Prototype cell because otherwise, I have to create 10 prototype. I have too many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I did two prototype cell and I only do the connection for one prototype cell. I have to do it for both. That's was the reason why Xcode found nil.

Resolved.

Many thanks